# ConnectException when one Kafka broker of cluster is down

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have two Kafka brokers: server1:9092 and server2:9092
I'm using a Java client to send a message to this cluster, this is the code:

```
@Test
public void sendRecordToTopic() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    //See at http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newproducerconfigs
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            "server1:9092,server2:9092");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "1");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);

    ProducerRecord<String, String> myRecord =
            new ProducerRecord<String, String>("my-replicated-topic", "test", "someValue");

    boolean syncSend = true;

    if (syncSend) {
        //Synchronously send
        producer.send(myRecord).get();
    } else {
        //Asynchronously send
        producer.send(myRecord);
    }
    producer.close();
}
```

When one of the brokers is down the Test in some cases throws this exception (in this exception example 'server1' was down):

> 2015-11-02 17:59:29,138 WARN 
>   [org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector] Error in I/O with
>   server1/40.35.250.227 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   no further information    at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>     at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:238)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:192)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:122)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way that I solve the problem:

- At least 3 ZooKeeper nodes are required, I have to configure one more. This is because the way that ZK determine the leader, it required more that the 50% of the nodes up and running.
- Add this parameter to ZooKeeper properties file:

  tickTime=200

This parameter is required to use those other parameters:

```
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
```

- Add this property in Producer:

  props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "10000");

With `"RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG"` property the WARN is thrown only once (not a infinite loop) and then the message is sent

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and it turns out that the cause is a misunderstanding of one of the new config properties.

In migrating from the previous producer API I looked for an equivalent to "topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms" and settled on ProducerConfig.METADATA_FETCH_TIMEOUT_CONFIG.  However this turns out to be the timeout before an attempt to access metadata is deemed a failure and since I was setting it to several minutes, it prevented failover from happening.

Setting this to a lower value (I chose 500ms) seems to have fixed my problem.

I believe that the value I was looking for originally was ProducerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG as the timeout before metadata is refreshed irrespective of whether a failure has occurred